# Need help putting several arrays from a JSONP call into one single array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, jsonp

I'm trying to get all viewers (people in chat) from a certain channel on twitch, into an array.

The JSONP call works, but the Twitch API returns several arrays:

- moderators
- staff
- admins
- global_mods
- viewers

I want to put all usernames that are in these arrays, into one single array (i.e. "peopleinchat").

My approach was to first declare the array:

`var peopleinchat= [];`

And then add each subsequent array (group) of people to this array using `$.merge()`. I can't get it to work however... I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". Can you help me out?

Thanks!

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/batuhanbuyukakkan/chatters",

  // The name of the callback parameter, as specified by the YQL service
  jsonp: "callback",

  // Tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
  dataType: "jsonp",

  // Work with the response
  success: function( response ) {

    var peopleinchat = [];

    $.each(response, function(index, data){

      $.each(data.chatters, function(index, group){

        $('.viewers').append(index + ': ' + group);
        $('.viewers').append('<br>');
        
        $.merge(peopleinchat, group);

      });

    });
    
    $('.array_result').append(peopleinchat);

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="viewers"></div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="array_result"></div>
```

Comment: I don't understand why I'm getting this `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. It doesn't seem to be related to putting the different arrays into one bigger array, but it does prevent the code from executing further than the last each-loop :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there - I think your main problem was that you didn't deal with the proper shape of the `result` parameter to your `success` callback. The snippet below works:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/batuhanbuyukakkan/chatters",

  // The name of the callback parameter, as specified by the YQL service
  jsonp: "callback",

  // Tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
  dataType: "jsonp",

  // Work with the response
  success: function( response ) {
    var peopleinchat = [];

    $.each(response.data.chatters, function(index, data){

        $('.viewers').append(index + ': ' + data);
        $('.viewers').append('<br>');
        
        $.merge(peopleinchat, data);

    });
    
    $('.array_result').append(peopleinchat);

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="viewers"></div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="array_result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right. Apparently I was getting the TypeError because I was looping through data.chatters, but this variable did not exist every time of the each() loop, because chatters was only one of the children of data. Thanks for your solution! It's way better than what I came up with just now: embedding the whole thing in an `if(data.chatters){ }`.

Comment: Follow up question: How do I get the variable `peopleinchat` to work outside of this ajax call? I tried moving the `var peopleinchat= [];` to the top, but that's not doing it. The data that was put into it during the ajax call is still not available outside of the ajax call.

Comment: EDIT: never mind, the problem was that the AJAX call takes longer to execute, so everything that uses the result had to be in the success {} section. Fixed it.